# Resolution detections on iOS Simulator using Phonegap

Tags: css, ios, cordova, xcode4, ios-simulator

I'm pretty new in this area of developing, and I'm trying to figure out the making of iOS app using Phonegap. I've created four different CSS files for different resolutions.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="only screen and (max-device-width: 1024px)" href="css/ipad.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="only screen and (max-device-width: 2048px)" href="css/ipad-retina.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="only screen and (max-device-width: 480px)" href="css/iphone.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="only screen and (max-device-width: 960px)" href="css/iphone-retina.css" type="text/css" />
```

I found out that the Simulator always loads the same CSS file, even if I change devices. Is there any way to make it load css files properly?

Thanks people and by the way is my CSS calling correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a way to achieve what you are after.  Include the specific CSS required in each section.

```
/* Non-Retina */
    @media screen and (-webkit-max-device-pixel-ratio: 1) {
    }

    /* Retina */
    @media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5),
    only screen and (-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 3/2),
    only screen and (min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5),
    only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5) {
    }

    /* iPhone Portrait */
    @media screen and (max-device-width: 480px) and (orientation:portrait) {
    } 

    /* iPhone Landscape */
    @media screen and (max-device-width: 480px) and (orientation:landscape) {
    }

    /* iPad Portrait */
    @media screen and (min-device-width: 481px) and (orientation:portrait) {
    }

    /* iPad Landscape */
    @media screen and (min-device-width: 481px) and (orientation:landscape) {
    }
```

Comment: Yes put all retina CSS, in the retina section